# Manipulating dynamic array through functions in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am learning how to use dynamic arrays in C. What I want to do is to create a dynamic array `data`, and put "1" into the first entry using the function `test()`.

```
void test(void)
{

data[0] = 1;

}


int main(void)
{

int *data = malloc(4 * sizeof *data);

test();

return 0;
}
```

This compiles in Visual Studio 2010 but the program crashes when run. Instead of using `test()`, using `data[0] = 1` works.

My (newbie) guess is that I need to pass a pointer to `data` to function `test()`. How should I write this?

**Attempt**

```
void test(int *data)
{

data[0] = 1;

}
```

Then, in `main` use `test(data)` instead of just `test()`.

**Edit**

The attempt works. However, is this a "proper" way of doing it?

Comment: Was your attempt successful ? If not what error did you get and what do you interpret from it ?

Comment: So far as I can see, your first attempt should never have compiled since `data` was not defined in the `test` function.  Your second attempt looks like it should have worked, what was the result?

Comment: @AshRj - The attempt worked! Is this the "proper" way of doing it though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass arrays dynamically in two ways :

- Using a simple pointer and then using pointer arithmetic to manipulate

```
void test (int * data, int i)
{
    *(data + i) = 1; //This sets data[i] = 1
}
```

- Or this way :

```
void test(int data[], int i)
{
    data[i] = 1; //This is the more familiar notation
}
```

---

Either of these ways is the 'proper' way to go about this.

Comment: My attempt worked. This actually doesn't. Thanks for the help in the comments. Do you want to revise your answer so I can accept it? Also, is this a "proper" way of doing it?

Comment: @Legendre, yes it is proper way.

Comment: @Legendre Well you simply need to call the test function with `test(data);` too from your main... Oh and, good practice, *don't* forget to `free` the memory you allocated. Since your program exits afterwards in this case the OS will handle it, but its good practice to always free the resources you allocated.

Comment: If you're implying that `int i` is the number of elements in the array, then you just accessed memory outside of it by using `data[i]`. If you're implying that the `int i` is just some static number like `0` to access the array `data`.. then that's pointless and you should just hardcode it.

Comment: `i` is the index to be manipulated. I am just giving a conceptual example for the OP (i agree that it is not the best example).

Answer (score 2):

When you use a local variable in C, (dynamic or static, array or not), you need to pass it to the function that will be using it. That's what's wrong with your initial code, `test()` doesn't know anything about `data`.

When you declare an array, (dynamic or static) you can pass it to the function in the same ways. The following code is pretty pointless, but it illustrates that using a dynamic array is really no different than a static array.

```
void assign_function(int arr[], int len_of_arr, int *arr2, int len_of_arr2);
void print_function(int *arr, int len_of_arr, int arr2[], int len_of_arr2);

int main()
{
    int data[2] = {0}; // static array of 2 ints
    int *data2 = malloc(3 * sizeof(int)); // dynamic array of 3 ints

    assign_function(data, 2, data2, 3);
    print_function(data2, 3, data, 2);

    free(data2); // One difference is you have to free the memory when you're done

    return 0;
}
```

So we can pass the arrays, be they dynamic or static, via `array[]` or as a pointer, but we need to pass an `int` along as well so we know how big the array is.

```
void assign_function(int arr[], int len_of_arr, int *arr2, int len_of_arr2)
{
    int count;
    for(count = 0; count < len_of_arr; count++) //This is the static array
        arr[count] = count;

    for(count = 0; count < len_of_arr2; count++) //This is the dynamic array
        arr2[count] = count;
}
```

Then just for fun I reverse which array is pass in `arr` and `arr2` here, and also how they're accessed:

```
void print_function(int *arr, int len_of_arr, int arr2[], int len_of_arr2)
{
    int count;
    for(count = 0; count < len_of_arr; count++)   //This is the dynamic array now
        printf("arr[%d] = %d\n", count, *(arr+count));

    for(count = 0; count < len_of_arr2; count++)  //And this is the static array
        printf("arr2[%d] = %d\n", count, *(arr2+count));
}
```

Point being, passing via `[]` or as a pointer, and accessing via `[]` or a deferenced pointer is up to you, both are fine, both work. I try to avoid pointers when I can as they tend to be hard to read and more error prone when writing.

Comment: Thanks for the lengthy explanation mike. +1

Answer (score 0):

The variable 'data' in test is locally scoped.  It's not the same 'data' that is in main.  You should pass a pointer to 'data' through the parameters of test().