# Manipulating dynamic array using realloc in a function

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

Using what I have learned here: [How to use realloc in a function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748338/how-to-use-realloc-in-a-function-in-c), I wrote this program.

```
int data_length; // Keeps track of length of the dynamic array.
int n; // Keeps track of the number of elements in dynamic array.

void add(int x, int data[], int** test)
{

    n++;

    if (n > data_length)
    {
        data_length++;
        *test = realloc(*test, data_length * sizeof (int));
    }

    data[n-1] = x;

}

int main(void)
{

    int *data = malloc(2 * sizeof *data);

    data_length = 2; // Set the initial values.
    n = 0;

    add(0,data,&data);
    add(1,data,&data);
    add(2,data,&data);

    return 0;
}
```

The goal of the program is to have a dynamic array `data` that I can keep adding values to. When I try to add a value to `data`, if it is full, the length of the array is increased by using realloc.

**Question**

This program compiles and does not crash when run. However, printing out `data[0]`,`data[1]`,`data[2]` gives `0,1,0`. The number `2` was not added to the array.

Is this due to my wrong use of `realloc`?

**Additional Info**

This program will be used later on with a varying number of "add" and possibly a "remove" function. Also, I know `realloc` should be checked to see if it failed (is `NULL`) but that has been left out here for simplicity.

I am still learning and experimenting with C. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Hint: as a formal parameter, `int data[]` is exactly the same as `int *data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in your utilisation of  `data`, because it points on the old array's address. Then, when your call `realloc`, this area is freed. So you are trying to access to an invalid address on the next instruction: this leads to an undefined behavior.

Also you don't need to use this `data` pointer. `test` is sufficient.

```
(*test)[n-1] = x;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass `data` twice to `add`.

You could code

```
void add(int x, int** ptr)
{
  n++;
  int *data = *ptr;
  if (n > data_length) {
    data_length++;
    *ptr = data = realloc(oldata, data_length * sizeof (int));
    if (!data) 
      perror("realloc failed), exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  data [n-1] = x;
}
```

but that is very inefficient, you should call `realloc` only once in a while. You could for instance have

```
     data_length = 3*data_length/2 + 5;
     *ptr = data = realloc(oldata, data_length * sizeof (int));
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. Especially about the inefficiency. +1

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at the [POSIX realloc specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/realloc.html).

The description says:

> If the new size of the memory object would require movement of the object, the space for the previous instantiation of the object is freed.

The return value (emphasis added) mentions:

> Upon successful completion with a size not equal to 0, realloc() returns a pointer to the (**possibly moved**) allocated space.

You can check to see if the pointer changes.

```
int *old;
old = *test;
*test = realloc(*test, data_length * sizeof(int));
if (*test != old)
    printf("Pointer changed from %p to %p\n", old, *test);
```

This possible change can interact badly because your code refers to the "same" memory by two different names, `data` and `*test`. If `*test` changes, `data` still points to the old chunk of memory.