# C++11 Error - What does this error mean when I try to dynamically increase the size of an array?

Tags: c++, c++11, dynamic-allocation

I am using this algorithm for dynamically increasing the size of an array:

```
void resize(int* oldArray, int* capacity) {
    *capacity = *capacity * 2;
    int* new_array = new int[*capacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < *capacity/2; i++) {
        new_array[i] = oldArray[i];
    }
    delete[] oldArray;
    oldArray = new_array;
}
```

However, when I build and run this algorithm I get the following error:

r3(21751,0x7fff8d76e340) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f8ca5c026c0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6

Also, this is the main function I am using:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        return -1;
    }

    std::ifstream inFile(argv[1]);
    int capacity = 10;
    int* num_array = new int[capacity];
    int num_elements = 0;

    if (inFile.is_open()) {
        std::string line;
        while (!inFile.eof()) {
            getline(inFile,line);
            if (num_elements == capacity) {
                resize(num_array,&capacity);
            }
            int num = stoi(line);
            num_array[num_elements++] = num;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < num_elements; i++) {
            std::cout<<num_array[i]<<std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone please tell me why this is happening? Thank you!

Comment: `oldArray = new_array;` This assignment is a no-op. Its effects are not visible to the caller of `resize`. The caller ends up with a dangling pointer, while the newly allocated buffer is leaked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use realloc in a function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748338/how-to-use-realloc-in-a-function-in-c)

Comment: Save yourself some trouble and learn to use a vector.

Comment: You should also delete `num_array` at the end of `main`.

Comment: Why C++11 tag? It's even more "C+" than C++.

Comment: @DanielLangr because OP is using a C++11 compiler and wants answers to target that standard. That his code is also valid C++03 for now is anecdotical.

Answer (score 3):

It means you're a "C+ programmer", that strange breed who appears to have not fully made the transition away from C :-)

Things such as using `malloc/free` (and even `new/delete` in these days of smart pointers), raw arrays rather than the standard collections, rolling your own code for things found in `<algorithms>`, using `printf` rather than streams, and so on, these are the things that you should generally steer clear of.

I'd suggest you look into using `std::vector` if you want resizable arrays, it's part of the language itself and has been well and truly tested <sup>(a)</sup>.

All that gumpf about resizing the array and adding your new element can then be replaced with a simple:

```
myVector.push_back(myElement);
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Yes, I'm well aware that it doesn't answer your *specific* question but, like writing an accounting package in assembler, developing your new operating system in object-oriented COBOL, or doing *anything* in Pascal :-), sometimes the right answer is "don't do that".

If you *do* insist on being a "C+ programmer", you should at least understand that everything you want to change in a function and have the effect returned to the caller, should be passed by reference. In this case, that's both your pointer *and* the capacity variable (there is *no* need to use C's hideous pointer-based pass-by-reference trickery in C++):

```
#include <algorithm>
:
void resize(int *&oldArray, int &capacity) {
    capacity *= 2;
    int newArray = new int[capacity];
    std::copy(oldArray, oldArray + capacity / 2, newArray);
    delete[] oldArray;
    oldArray = newArray;
}
```

You'll see a few improvements there, specifically:

- proper pass-by-reference for the variables.
- using `std::copy` to copy elements, rather than coding your own loop.
- consistent naming (not strictly necessary but useful to satisfy my CDO <sup>(b)</sup>).

---

<sup>(b)</sup> OCD but in the correct damn order :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need a `&`

```
// ...............V
void resize(int * & oldArray, int* capacity) {
*capacity = *capacity * 2;
int* new_array = new int[*capacity];
for (int i = 0; i < *capacity/2; i++) {
    new_array[i] = oldArray[i];
}
delete[] oldArray;
oldArray = new_array;
}
```

If you pass a pointer to `resize()`, without a `&` to pass it by **reference**, you pass it by **copy**. So you can change the values of the pointed integers but not the value of pointer itself.

With

```
int* num_array = new int[capacity];
```

you dynamically allocate an area, the first one.

With the first call to

```
resize(num_array,&capacity);
```

the area is destroied (inside `resize()`) and a second area is allocated but lost because, in `main()`, `num_array` maintain the value of the first area.

With the second call to

```
resize(num_array,&capacity);
```

the first allocated area is deleted for the second time.

Crash!

Passing `oldArray` as reference, the value of the new allocated area is assigned to the `num_array` variable in `main()`.

Comment: `capacity` should also be a reference, there is zero need to use the painful C method of emulating pass-by-reference in C++ :-)

Comment: Obviously you're right. I was undecided whether to write it in my answer. There were a lot of things to write about the code in the question (and you wrote a lot of things :-) ) but I was afraid to discourage the OP and I tried to focus on the point that caused the error.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a **reference** of pointer `num_array` in case you want to allocate new memory for this pointer, which means

you should change `void resize(int* oldArray, int* capacity)` to `void resize(int* & oldArray, int* capacity)`.

The reason behind this is that, when you calling function `resize` with passing argument `num_array`, you just created a **new pointer type variable** called **oldArray** and initialized it with the same value of `num_array` in the function body.

So when you new a memory, you just **allocated memory for this new variable** `oldArray` but not for the argument `num_array`. But when you calling `delete[] oldArray`, it's actually freed the memory you had allocated for `num_array` since `oldArray` has the same value with `num_array` here.

To get rid of this problem, you should just pass the reference of `num_array`.

Comment: Deleting a null pointer is well-defined. No need to check it first.

Comment: I have checked the reference, you are right. `delete` has already done this checking for me. Thanks for pointing out my incorrectness. I have deleted this part.@RetiredNinja