# How to add items to a 2D "ArrayList" in C and search for items in it

Tags: c

```
struct item {
    char name[100];
    double price;
} item;


char name[100];
int shelf;
int slot;
float price;
int NumOfShelves = 50
int NumOfSlotsPerShelf = 2
struct item *arrayl = (int *) malloc(NumOfShelves * NumOfSlotsPerShelf * sizeof(int));
```

//this is my "arraylist" ^ i think

```
printf("Add an item name);
scanf("%s", &name);
printf("Add an item price);
scanf("%f", &price);
printf("Add the shelf number of the item");
scanf("%d", &shelf);
printf("Add the slot number");
scanf("%d", &slot);
```

//on this line. How do I add an item to that slot and shelf in my arrayl?

```
printf("Search for an item by first giving the shelf number:");
scanf("%d", &slot);
printf("Search by giving the slot number");
scanf("%d", &slot);
```

//if arrayl contains the location

//print name and price of item in that location

```
else {
printf("None")
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want an array of `struct item`? And I don't see any 2D array here whatsoever... Please read this: [ask] and then [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: int *arrayl = (int *) malloc(NumOfShelves * NumOfSlotsPerShelf * sizeof(int)); Isn't this an array? Yes, I want an array of struct items. How would I go about this?

Comment: Yes that's more or less an array of `int` but not an array of `struct item`s. See answer below.

Comment: To be clear, `int *arrayl = (int *) malloc(NumOfShelves * NumOfSlotsPerShelf * sizeof(int))`; _Isn't this an array?_  No, it is a collection of pointers to specific locations in memory. `int array1[10][20] = {0};` is an example of a `C` array.  Both allow use of index notation to access _elements_ of the collection, but only one is an actual array.

Comment: @johnjacob Please do **not** make significant changes to a question that has already been answered. It invalidates the answer given which ruin the whole QA idea. If you still have problems after using the advice in the answer, you should instead write a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Your array has the wrong type. Use

```
struct item *arrayl = malloc(NumOfShelves * NumOfSlotsPerShelf * sizeof *array1);
^^^^^^^^^^^                                                              ^^^^^^
```

Then you simply do:

```
array1[shelf * NumOfSlotsPerShelf + slot].price = price;
```

Kind of the same for the name but you need `strcpy` instead of `=`

```
strcpy(array1[shelf * NumOfSlotsPerShelf + slot].name, name);
```

An alternative way of doing `malloc` is:

```
 int NumOfShelves = 50;
 int NumOfSlotsPerShelf = 2;
 struct item (*array1)[NumOfSlotsPerShelf] = malloc(NumOfShelves * sizeof *array1);
```

This will allow you to write items in the array like:

```
array1[shelf][slot].price = price;
strcpy(array1[shelf][slot].name, name);
```

**note**

Using `malloc` means that all items in the array are initially uninitialized. It may be a better idea to use `calloc` so that all items are zero initialized.

Comment: The index should be `shelf * NumOfSlotsPerShelf + slot`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Hi. Thanks so much! I decided to use the second Malloc as it provides an easier way to search for items. The only problem I see is that i am unable to use the first methods you suggested (regarding adding items to the array) on the second malloc. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @johnjacob The answer shows how to write to items in the array for both types of malloc.

Comment: @johnjacob if you are asking how you would change the memory to allow more items after it has already been `malloc`'ed, _[realloc](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_realloc.htmhttps://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_realloc.htm)_ is how you would do that.  But be aware, of some of the subtleties of using it: _[How to use realloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748338/how-to-use-realloc-in-a-function-in-c)_.

Comment: you have to change the '.' to -> I believe

Comment: @johnjacob No, it has to be `.` Why do you think it has to be `->` ?

Comment: @johnjacob If you get an error then you did not copy my code correctly. see https://ideone.com/DstFXh

Comment: https://ideone.com/xj3PBM on line 53 an 54. the error is:  member reference base type 'struct item' [NumOfSlotsPerShelf] is not a structure or union.

Comment: I know that this code is different than the one i wrote on stack overflow, it is slightly more advanced